# change Visual Studio toolbars - customize location of comment out / uncomment out

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2013 Premium, I would like to add the "Comment Out" and "Uncomment Out" icons to the Text Edit Toolbar (to be near the bookmark icons).

However, when I go into Text Editor Toolbar drop down for Add or Remove Buttons. and then > Customize > Add Command, I cannot locate the Comment Out and Uncomment Out buttons in any of the Categories. (In Premium their default location is on the "Standard" toolbar).

Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I'm trying to do would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find them in the **Edit** category as **Selection Comment** and **Selection Uncomment**.

Answer (score 12):

Click on the Add/Remove buttons in the toolbar.  Select Customize.

[image: Add/Remove Button - Customize]
[image: Select Text Editor]

Answer (score 2):

[image: It is working !]
why it is not working in your perspective !

Comment: I am able to add other icons to the Text Edit toolbar, by going to Text Editor Toolbar drop down for Add or Remove Buttons. and then > Customize > Add Command, and looking in the Categories for what I want.  However, I cannot locate the Comment/Uncomment icons in any of the Categories.